# Converting label to X-axis in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, dashboard, grafana-templating

I have the following prometheus metrics scraping from an exporter and the label has the correct “time” I want to use in X axis instead of “Time”.

Is it possible to convert/transform “time” label as x axis?

[image]

Thank you!